# window.open and window.location in the same script

Tags: asp.net

I have a small problem, I have a linkbutton that I am linking to a public sub that does the following:

```
 Dim url As String = "articledownload.aspx?articleID=" & LatestNewsLetter.ArticleID
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "OpenWin", "<script>window.open('" & url & "'); window.location('newsReleases.aspx')</script>")
```

This works with IE, but not chrome.  I have tried switching the order of the scripts around but with the same results.  I am trying to open a new window with a file download and at the same time redirect the current page to another location.  Is there another method of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
window.location.href = 'newsReleases.aspx';
```

In order to do the second bit of redirecting the main page.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jV9PJ/).